# I keep getting the error "[Errno 21] Is a directory:" when recalling a text file from a zipped file

Tags: python, file, directory

I have a zipped file that I have unzipped that contains text files in the date format "yyyymmdd.txt" and when I try recalling a certain date's file I keep getting the error shown below.

Here is me unzipping the file:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("ALL_FOMC_MINUTES_1990_2021.zip","r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('20200315.text')
```

When I try cleaning the code and importing other text files they all work except for the "20200315" one

```
import re
def Text(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    text = f.read()                       
    f.close()
    return text

mainfile=Text('20200315.txt')
file1 =Text('1.6_LM_negative.txt')
file2=Text('1.6_LM_positive.txt')
file3=Text('StopWords_Generic.txt')
```

This is the traceback and error it gives me:
[image]

Comment: The argument to `extractall()` is the name of the directory to extract all the files into. So it creates a directory named `20200315.text`, and puts all the files from the archive into it. What did you think it did?

Comment: If you want to extract the member named `20200315.text` you should use `extract()`, not `extractall()`.

Comment: I've tried the extract() method with the same error as my outcome

Comment: You need to delete the directory so that you can extract the file with that name.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, formatted like code.

Comment: Note that there is `zip_ref.extractall('20200315.text')` (i.e. `.text`) and `mainfile=Text('20200315.txt')` (i.e. `.txt`); they are not the same. Hence, more information is required.

Comment: How would I delete a directory? And I fixed my text error but now it's telling me it can't find the file even though it's there

Comment: when I use extract() but when extractall() runs it runs fine